# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main PID: 5112

Tags: android

Hy

I am new to Android / Java is I am facing a BMO problem
I code it but it does not work

an idea ??

thank you

```
<string name="onCreate_Go">onCreate Go</string>

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scrollTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

import android.widget.TextView;
```

private  final TextView txt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.scrollTxt);

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt.setText(R.string.onCreate_Go);
}
```

5112-5112/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.gmail.test1, PID: 5112
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gmail.test1/com.gmail.test1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:54)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:202)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                                                     at com.gmail.test1.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:13)
                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-16 16:41:21.634 5112-5112/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5112 SIG: 9

Comment: Trying to initialize the txt variable before the onCreate method will have null value cause you didnt setContentView yet. move it to the method onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Please add your `Activity` in your  `AndroidManifest.xml`. like below code:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"/>
```

Also put the `findViewById()` after `setContentView()` so it can actually return something other than null.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize the textView before call "setContentView" method. I recommend you create a "init" method where initialize all layout's elements and call it after "setContentView"